# Bash inserts script parameters into string

Tags: c, bash, shell, replace

I am very tired because of a problem:
I want to run a bash script that automatically creates me another bash script, which in turn should already contain C code that just gets compiled and run on the fly while its output gets piped to aplay.
My example is based on the [ComputerPhile bitshift variations code](https://youtu.be/MqZgoNRERY8).

I have a C script like this (should get replaced and developed later):

```
g(i, x, t, o) {
    return ((3 & x & (i * (
        (3 & i >> 16 ? "BY}6YB6%" : "Qj}6jQ6%")[t%8] + 51
    ) >> o)) << 4);
};

main(i, n, s) {
    for (i = 0; ;i++)
        putchar(
            g(i, 1, n = i >> 14, 12) +
            g(i, s = i >> 17, n^i >> 13, 10) +
            g(i, s/3, n + ((i >> 11) % 3), 10) +
            g(i, s/5, 8 + n - ((i >> 10) % 3), 9)
        );
}
```

and I want to 
 1. minify it and
 2. escape the `"` characters to `\"`
to get a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "g(i,x,t,o){return((3&x&(i*((3&i>>16?\"BY}6YB6%\":\"Qj}6jQ6%\")[t%8]+51)>>o))<<4);};main(i,n,s){for(i=0;;i++)putchar(g(i,1,n=i>>14,12)+g(i,s=i>>17,n^i>>13,10)+g(i,s/3,n+((i>>11)%3),10)+g(i,s/5,8+n-((i>>10)%3),9));}"|gcc -xc -&&./a.out|aplay
```

However, I cannot seem to come near that goal. Either it does make an empty string (`echo ""|gcc ...`) or it weirdly pastes the script parameters in (`...return ((3 & x & (i c2sh.sh tmp waveform.c waveform.sh ( (3 & i >> 16 ? BY}6YB6%...`, but I already had a version of this where the `"` got replaced correctly).

My code (without cleanup so you can see two other things I tried) is currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '#!/bin/bash' > tmp

out=''

echo $(cat waveform.c | tr '"' ' ')

#while read line; do 
#    out+="$line"
#done < 'waveform.c'

#out=$(echo $out | sed 's/"/\\"/g')
out=${out/"/\\"}

echo 'echo "'$out'" | gcc -xc -&& ./a.out | aplay' >> tmp

mv tmp 'waveform.sh'
chmod +x 'waveform.sh'
```

What the heck is going on and how should this be done correctly?

Comment: Why minify it at all? Why not incorporate it into a heredoc with all its formatting and whitespace intact?

Comment: That is to say -- it'd be a lot cleaner if the wrapper you generated was something like https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/a8b4602aaccfe73c398289eaf43f477d.

Comment: To speak to what was going on with your original code -- in `echo 'echo "'$out'" | gcc -xc -&& ./a.out | aplay'`, the `$out` expansion is happening completely unquoted -- that is to say, outside any syntactic quotes. Consequently, the results of that expansion are prone to string-splitting and glob expansion -- meaning, for instance, that a `*` in the expanded code gets treated as an instruction to replace it with filesystem contents if there are any local files whose names match.

Comment: That you were removing whitespace first makes it a little less likely that globs would actually *expand*, but this was still setting up a bunch of hard-to-predict behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correctly? It **shouldn't** be done. In bash, code generation is a "smell", contrary to accepted best practices.

However, if you're going to do it anyway, let the shell do the escaping, rather than trying to write your own logic (which will almost without exception be prone to shell injection vulnerabilities):

```
#!/bin/bash
infile=${1:-waveform.c}           # read name from command-line argument if given
content=$(<"$infile")             # $(<foo) is more efficient than $(cat foo)
content=${content//[[:space:]]/}  # trim spaces from variable contents

# put the arguments to the command you want to generate into an array
cmd=( printf '%s\n' "$content" )

# tell the shell to generate a string which has each element of that array escaped
printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"

# put our generated contents into an array, one line per each;
# not essential, but makes it easy to comment each line we generate below.
output=(
  '#!/bin/bash'                  # using bash ensures that printf %q-generated code works.
  "$cmd_q | gcc -xc - || exit"   # use our generated string for all non-constant code.
  './a.out | aplay'
)
printf '%s\n' "${output[@]}"     # finally, emit output with all of the above
```

---

Items of note:

- `printf '%q'` formats a given shell variable in such a way that, when evaluated by a shell, it will evaluate back to its original literal contents. This is essential not just for correctness, but also for security: If you were listening to waveforms from someone else's code, you wouldn't want `/* $(rm -rf ~) */` to be evaluated by your shell.
- `echo` is a very ambiguously-specified command, in order to allow wildly different implementations by various historical operating systems to all comply with [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). As POSIX recommends, `printf` should be used instead in any case where the data is not hand-generated and known not to trigger any of the ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful C Minifier *python script on GitHub, [`minifier.py`](https://github.com/Scylardor/cminify), which might help:

```
code=`python minifier.py waveform.c`
echo "$code" ## `printf "%s\n" "$code"` is safer though...
```

Output:

> g(i,x,t,o){return((3&x&(i*((3&i>>16 ? "BY}6YB6%" :
>   "Qj}6jQ6%")[t%8]+51)>>o))<<4);};main(i,n,s){for(i=0;;i++)putchar(g(i,1,n=i>>14,12)+g(i,s=i>>17,n^i>>13,10)+g(i,s/3,n+((i>>11)%3),10)+g(i,s/5,8+n-((i>>10)%3),9));}

For a more general fix [*C. Duffy*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660651/6136214) quotes every char, a *100%* increase, using some kind of [binary to hex encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) would be more efficient, albeit meaningless to humans, e.g.:

```
python minifier.py waveform.c | base64 
ZyhpLHgsdCxvKXtyZXR1cm4oKDMmeCYoaSooKDMmaT4+MTYgPyAiQll9NllCNiUiIDogIlFqfTZq
UTYlIilbdCU4XSs1MSk+Pm8pKTw8NCk7fTttYWluKGksbixzKXtmb3IoaT0wOztpKyspcHV0Y2hh
cihnKGksMSxuPWk+PjE0LDEyKStnKGkscz1pPj4xNyxuXmk+PjEzLDEwKStnKGkscy8zLG4rKChp
Pj4xMSklMyksMTApK2coaSxzLzUsOCtuLSgoaT4+MTApJTMpLDkpKTt9Cg==
```

Which is unreadable, but so is escaped minified C...